# visual studio 2022 enterprise git------- fatal: unexpected sequence from git rev-parse encountered

Tags: visual-studio, github

Clone and commit failed in VS2022 and it said “fatal: unexpected sequence from git rev-parse encountered.”.[fatal: unexpected sequence from git rev-parse encountered.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhnBi.jpg)

What’s more , when changes code files, it does’t trace the changed files and gives a status change on the right-bottom corner.[error tip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uErSF.jpg)

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/fatal-unexpected-sequence-from-git-rev-parse-encou-1/702324,
The Microsoft developer community has a similar problem, but I can't solve it here without me

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem in Visual Studio 2022. After trying various solutions, eventually this worked for me:
find`C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualC.Redist.12,version=12.0.30501.1,chip=x64` does the folder exist,If the folder exists manually install vcredist_x64.exe,If it does not exist, you can try to download the [vcredist](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-CN/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170vcredist_x64.exe)  installation package to install,Once installed, restart your computer and see if it works.I hope this helps you.